# Can you identify this window frame construction from the ID sticker?

Tags: window-frame

This is the information on the sticker that is on the window.

> ANSI/AAMA-101-93 MST 3860 CODE J. 093-1 SPEC DH-R25 SERIES 105/155

Comment: Is there anything else on the sticker? Could you provide a picture of it? Also, I edited the title to ask what I think you're asking and added a bit of formatting. If I got it wrong, please feel free to [edit] again.

Answer (score 2):

Most of that code is American National Standards Institute and American Architectural Manufacturer's Association structural ratings.

The biggest clue is `SERIES 105/155`, which seems to correlate to [Lowes' Reliabilt brand](https://www.lowes.com/pd/ReliaBilt-105-Vinyl-Egress-New-Construction-White-Exterior-Single-Hung-Window-Rough-Opening-36-in-x-60-in-Actual-35-5-in-x-59-5-in/50273243), but it could also be a ratings category.